# Error Webservice Genexus usando variable location

Tags: java, soap, genexus, wsdl

Cordial saludo,

Estoy usando GX 16 U9.

Mi problema es el siguiente, al momento de ejecutar mi WS esta apareciendo el siguiente mensaje:

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.(-5)

El error aparece cuando uso la variable location. Este es el código que tengo para consumir el WS:

```
&location = getlocation('PConsultaPredio')
&location.Host = 'realidad5.com' 
&location.Port = 8445
&location.Secure= 1
&location.BaseUrl = '/realmultipropositoibague/servlet/'

&PConsultaPredioSPredioC=&PConsultaPredio.Execute(&documento, &tipo)
```

El WSDL lo importo con la herramienta WSDL Import que configura el External Object de forma automatica, llegando a pensar que aqui puede estar el inconveniente.

Este es el WSDL:

https://realidad5.com:8445/realmultipropositoibague/servlet/com.realmultipropositogam.apconsultapredio?wsdl

El WS lo he probado con SOAPUI y funciona sin problema, concluyendo que el problema no esta en el proveedor sino en el consumidor.

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

veo que el servicio que intentas consumir se encuentra bajo https, por lo tanto tienes que importar los certificados para poder consumirlo con éxito. Te recomiendo que leas este link:

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?4300,Consumir+servicios+web+bajo+https+y%2Fo+autenticaci%C3%B3n

(Allí vas a encontrar un link a otro doc dónde se especifíca como importar los certificado en Java).